# SQL Query - Find Missing Info

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can find questions and answers along a similar line to mine, but nothing that I can seem to interpret...

I'm trying to get some data for a c# winforms application. I would prefer to have this as a view in my database that I can access using linqtosql. I just have no idea how to go about it. I realise I could use loops to build the table I want using C#, but was hoping that a single query would achieve the same thing more efficiently.

I have three tables with the following fields:

1. WeekTable
   *Week (Integer)*
2. UserTable
   *User (String)*
   *Start Week (Integer)*
3. SubmissionTable
   *User (String)*
   *Week (Integer)*
   *Status (String)*

I want a query which checks each User against the SubmissionTable, looking for an entry for every week greater than or equal to their start week.

For every week checked for that user, if there is no entry in the submission table, or the entry in the submission table has status "Incomplete" I want the query to return the user name and the missing week. I'm basically after a query result listing all missing or incomplete entries.

**For example:**
WeekTable contains five records, 1-5
UserTable contains two records "User A" who has a start week of 2 and "User B" who has a start week of 5
SubmissionTable contains 3 records:
     *User A, 2, Complete*
     *User A, 3, Incomplete*
     *User A, 5, Complete*

User A is missing an entry for week 1, but that can be ignored because their start week was 2, they are also missing an entry for week 4, and the entry they have submitted for week 3 is incomplete. User B started in week 5 so there should be an entry for that, but it is missing.

The query result I'd want would be as follows:
*User A, 3*
*User A, 4*
*User B, 5*

Can anyone assist me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things - building the combination of weeks and users, and checking for the missing values

```
select uw.* from 
    (
        select [user], [week]
        from users
            inner join weeks on users.startweek<=weeks.[week]
    ) uw
        left join 
    submissions
        on uw.[user]= submissions.[user]
        and uw.[week] = submissions.[week]
        and submissions.[status]='complete'
where submissions.[user] is null
```

Instead of looking for incomplete or missing, I look for complete, and exclude them.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even think about trying it this way, such an elegant solution! Thanks!

I replaced the week integers with dates (used integers above to simplify my question) and then to limit my list to entries within the last two months and to prevent looking at weeks later than the last week I change the last bit to:  

        where submissions.[user] is null  
        and uw.[week] < DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())  
        and uw.[week] > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())